# Matlab dynamic properties with restricted access to addprop

Tags: matlab, oop

I'm creating a toolbox and I  would like to dynamically add specific properties to instances of a class, while limiting the users' ability to add properties.

I'm considering a baseline functionality for class of objects, called Models. Each of the models can be decorated with additional functionality, like Bootstrap CI's, permutation tests, etc.

I want the additional functionality to be appended to the object instances. From what I understand using a decorator pattern would store instances of my model within it, but then I'm not sure what to do if I have multiple decorators acting on the same object - for example both boot CI's and permutation tests. I thought that adding dynamically properties to the object, only through calling a method defined for the class of models, would be the best option, but I don't know how to program that, while making it impossible for users to add properties to the objects.

Comment: a more detailed description of your use case is necessary; what do you want to add? what should the user be able to do, in which way should the user be limited etc. please give an example

Comment: @m.s., see edited post.

Comment: why should users be prohibited to add properties?

Comment: @m.s. my reasoning was that it would make it robust. I want it to produce results that are re-usable or easily exchangeable between different groups (of users).

Comment: Dynamic properties are rarely the right design, and there are typically other solutions that are a better fit once you think things through. To propose a better design, one would need more information: are you going to have lots of subclasses of `Model`? Do some of them have bootstrap CIs and not others? Do they always have them, or only after the model has been fit? Are the CIs and permutation tests really properties at all, or should they be methods (e.g. `calculateBootstrapCI`)? Are models created and modified directly by users, or by some other part of your code?

Comment: @SamRoberts, I foresee at the moment at least 5 subclasses of Model.  Depending on how the sub-Models are trained, they will have different CI estimates (bootstrap, posterior variance, etc), and while they're methods I think it's crucial that if they are computed, they are stored in the object instances (the project is in part about making data analysis results management easier). The models are created by the users, i.e. objects created by the users given some input.

Comment: So all subclasses of model will have a CI estimate, but they will be calculated in different ways for each subclass? Do they always have a CI estimate, or do they perhaps only get a CI estimate during the model fitting process, or perhaps only after an additional post-fit step?

Comment: @SamRoberts. The CI estimate can be calculated in a different way for each subclass, and they are calculated only after an additional (and optional) post-fit step.

Answer (score 2):

This admittedly relatively old question popped up as a search result when I wanted to achieve the same functionality as per the title: Using dynamic properties but restricting the usage of `addprop`. And although I agree with the comments and the previous answer that dynamic properties should generally be avoided, I think I was able to find an answer which satisfies the original question.

My idea would be to have a class that inherits from [`dynamicprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dynamicprops-class.html) and [modifies](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modifying-superclass-methods-and-properties.html) (i.e., overrides) the inherited [`addprop`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dynamicprops.addprop.html) function. This way, you can for example add a condition that the call to `addprop` must come from a specific function (using [`dbstack`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html)) or you can add a private logical "lock" property to the calss that can internally be accessed to allow or disallow the usage of the modified `addprop` function. Changing the state of this "lock" and adding a new property can then be grouped into a separate function which is only internally accessible. Here are two short examples for both approaches:

**Model.m** (with condition on stack)

```matlab
classdef Model < dynamicprops
    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = Model()
            obj@dynamicprops();

            obj.internalAddProperty("Test", 5);
        end

        function storeSumAsProperty(obj, a, b)
            obj.internalAddProperty("Sum", a + b);
        end

        function addprop(obj, prop)
            % The caller of this function must be 'Model.internalAddProperty'
            [ST,I] = dbstack(1);
            if isempty(ST) || ~strcmp(ST(I).name, [mfilename(), '.internalAddProperty'])
                error("Adding a new property to this instance is not allowed.");
            end

            % Call original implementation if not locked
            addprop@dynamicprops(obj, prop);
        end
    end

    methods (Access = protected)
        function internalAddProperty(obj, prop, value)
            % The only thing this function does is add a new "layer" to the call stack
            obj.addprop(prop);
            obj.(prop) = value;
        end
    end
end
```

**Model.m** (with "lock" property)

```matlab
classdef Model < dynamicprops
    properties (Access = private)
        propertiesLocked (1,1) logical = false
    end

    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = Model()
            obj@dynamicprops();

            obj.addprop("Test");
            obj.Test = 5;
            obj.propertiesLocked = true;
        end

        function storeSumAsProperty(obj, a, b)
            obj.internalAddProperty("Sum", a + b);
        end

        function addprop(obj, prop)
            if obj.propertiesLocked
                error("Adding a new property to this instance is not allowed.");
            end

            % Call original implementation if not locked
            addprop@dynamicprops(obj, prop);
        end
    end

    methods (Access = protected)
        function internalAddProperty(obj, prop, value)
            obj.propertiesLocked = false;
            obj.addprop(prop);
            obj.propertiesLocked = true;
            obj.(prop) = value;
        end
    end
end
```

When using any of the two provided classes from the Matlab command window we get the following behavior:

```matlab
>> m = Model()
m = 
  Model with properties:

    Test: 5

>> m.storeSumAsProperty(5, 10)
>> m
m = 
  Model with properties:

     Sum: 15
    Test: 5

>> m.addprop("NewProp")
Error using Model/addprop
Adding a new property to this instance is not allowed.

>> addprop(m, "NewProp")
Error using Model/addprop
Adding a new property to this instance is not allowed.
```

Creating subclasses is also possible for both approaches. Any subclass will be able to use the function `internalAddProperty` to add dynamic properties. If subclasses should not be able to add dynamic properties, the access modifier for the function `internalAddProperty` must be set to `private`.

**One final note:** Because the content of function `internalAddProperty` for the second approach (i.e., unlocking, calling `addprop`, and locking again) is not executed atomically, there *might* be problems with race conditions in some very specific situations.

Comment: Race conditions? MATLAB is single-threaded, isn't it?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I believe so, yes. But I'm not 100% sure about Matlabs behavior when using the Parallel Computing Toolbox or event-driven programming (or both). It might be that Matlab just queues function calls in those situations and executes them serially, so that race conditions cannot occur. But I just wanted to give a hint that generally speaking race conditions should be considered with an implementation like this...

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach the design using Dependent properties and overloaded methods, rather than dynamic properties. For example:

**Model.m**

```
classdef (Abstract) Model < handle
    properties (Access = public)
        commonProp1
        commonProp2 % etc        
    end
    properties (Dependent, GetAccess = public, SetAccess = private)
        ciEstimate
    end
    properties (Access = private)
        isFitted = false;
        ciEstimateInternal = []
    end
    methods (Abstract, Access = public)
        ciEstimate = calcCIEstimate(obj)
        fit(obj)
    end
    methods
        function val = get.ciEstimate(obj)
            if ~obj.isFitted
                error('Model not yet fitted.')
            end
            if isempty(obj.ciEstimateInternal)
                obj.ciEstimateInternal = obj.calcCIEstimate;
            end
            val = obj.ciEstimateInternal;
        end
    end
end
```

**Type1Model.m**

```
classdef Type1Model < Model
    methods (Access = public)
        function fit(obj)
            % Do some fitting stuff for a type 1 model
            obj.isFitted = true;
        end
        function ciEstimate = calcCIEstimate(obj)
            % Do it in a bootstrap way
        end
    end
end
```

**Type2Model.m**

```
classdef Type2Model < Model
    methods (Access = public)
        function fit(obj)
            % Do some fitting stuff for a type 2 model
            obj.isFitted = true;
        end
        function ciEstimate = calcCIEstimate(obj)
            % Do it in a posterior variance way
        end
    end
end
```

Using this design, each model type can be fit in its own way, and can calculate CI estimates in its own way. Models will have a consistent property `ciEstimate`, that is calculated on demand the first time it's accessed, but otherwise is stored internally in the model object (in `ciEstimateInternal`).